# Debian Jessie initramfs-tools strange behavior

Tags: shell, debian, initramfs

My current system is:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.1 (jessie)
Release:    8.1
Codename:   jessie
```

with kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I updated to new kernel with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64
....
Setting up linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 (3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u2) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fsck: syntax error at line 60: `MNT_FSNAME=$' unexpected
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/keymap: syntax error at line 57: `value=$' unexpected
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/resume: syntax error at line 44: `RESUME=$' unexpected
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/zz-busybox: syntax error at line 33: `$' unexpected
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/plymouth: syntax error at line 19: `$' unexpected
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top/all_generic_ide: syntax error at line 16: `$' unexpected
....
```

I noticed errors from `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fsck` script, I check it and notice that it start with `#!/bin/sh` and line 60 is:

```
MNT_FSNAME=$(resolve_device "$MNT_FSNAME")
```

Well, I see that the error is from command substitution syntax. My `/bin/sh` is symlink to `dash` and `dash` of course support that syntax.

My system also have [sh from heirloom tool chests](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html), which was installed in `/usr/5bin/sh`, and that shell does not support `$(...)` syntax. So It seems that the script had been run with that shell instead of `/bin/sh` as its shebang.

What make that weird behavior and how to solve it?

**Updated**

There's also a `/sbin/sh` which is a symlink to `/usr/5bin/sh`. The problem solved after I removed this link. So the process that update initramfs seem to use it instead of `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @Gilles: Do you have any ideal why heirloom toolchests was used instead of `/bin/sh`?

Comment: I suppose the scripts are run as `sh the-script` where `PATH` has `/sbin` before `/bin`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Yeah, I also think like that, too. But how can we confirm that?

Comment: `strace -fe execve` would confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is script which ran the initramfs hook was called with `/sbin/sh`, which is old Bourne shell from heirloom tool chests in my system, instead of `/bin/sh`.

A `strace` can verify it:

```
$ strace -fe execve apt-get install linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64
...
22900 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=22918, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
22919 execve("/sbin/sh", ["sh", "-n", "/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks"...], [/* 40 vars */]) = 0
...
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem on Linux is that many scripts need non-portable bash features but do not flag this in their #! line.

There are other similar problems, e.g. scripts that call "awk" instead of "gawk" but rely on gawk features.

There are scripts that call utilities using GNUisms like non-portable long options.

Some people call this the vendor-lock-in from Linux. The reason why this happens is most likely the documentation from Linux. The Linux man pages do not mention non-portable "features" and fail to encourage people to use the portable options only.

Back to the shell. Using the heirloom shell is not a good idea at all as it is not really portable. The fact that it still uses sbrk() to allocate memory instead of malloc() causes various problems on various platforms. There may be hidden problems related to this fact on some Linux distros. It e.g. does not work at all on Cygwin for this reason. The heirloom shell did not fix any of the well known bugs from the SVr4 shell and this seems to be caused by the fact that development stopped after half a year.

If the heirloom shell was portable, it could be used as a test tool for hand-crafted script checking - for scripts that need to run everywhere. For dayly use, the heirloom shell is not the right decision.

BTW: if you like a portable version of the Svr4 Bourne shell for testing purposes, I recommend the Bourne Shell compiled as "osh" in the Schily-toolset. If you like to try to use a Bourne Shell for dayly use, I encourage people to check the Bourne Shell "bosh" from the Schily Toolset. It inludes the first history editor and thus will not cause you to scream all the time you are trying to use it.

Comment: Well, this answer is not answer my question. The edited title seems to be confused, going to updated it.

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly you like to know. Let me reply directly to the first visible low level inline question: $(cmd) is not supported by the Bourne Shell, use `cmd`instead.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I wonder why the update-initramfs hook was failed, that's because it use `sh script` with `PATH` have `/sbin` before `/bin`. And my `/sbin/sh` is heirloom `sh`.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case ay you got a syntax error message related to $()